# Raspberry pi does not detect compass sensor

Tags: pi-4, i2c, sensor, mpu6050

I have a GY-91 sensor connected to raspberry pi 4B+ and only mpu6050(accelerometer, gyroscope) address 0x68 is getting detected while the compass sensor address 0x0C is not.

```
$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

My connection is as follows: 3V3 -> 3.3V
,GND -> GND
,SCL -> SCL(GPIO 3)
,SDA -> SDA(GPIO 2)

What could be the problem?

Comment: 0x00 is not a legal I2C address.

Comment: sorry, the address is 0x0C, not 0x00.